# Apply For Loop to SQL Import

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file datetable that looks like this-table name is `combined`:

```
author    shift_start                   shift_end
Brown       2022-11-01 11:00:00        2022-11-01 15:00:00
Crandell    2022-11-01 11:00:00        2022-11-01 15:00:00
Garzone     2022-11-01 11:00:00        2022-11-01 15:00:00
Molinari    2022-11-01 11:00:00        2022-11-01 15:00:00
Brown       2022-11-01 15:00:00        2022-11-01 19:00:00
Crandell    2022-11-01 15:00:00        2022-11-01 19:00:00
Garzone     2022-11-01 15:00:00        2022-11-01 19:00:00
Molinari    2022-11-01 15:00:00        2022-11-01 19:00:00
Brown       2022-11-01 19:00:00        2022-11-01 23:00:00
```

I want to import data from an SQL table only when each of the two conditions are both met within the `combined` table:

1. The `author` name
2. The date of the visit was between the `shift_start` and `shift_end` time.

SQL Table (the `NOTES` table in the code below)

```
ID    RESULT_DT_TM           Author
1      2022-11-01 12:34.00   Brown
2      2022-11-01 12:14.00   White
3      2022-11-01 07:38.00   Garzone     
4      2022-11-01 14:22.00   Molinari
```

So when applying the code, it would import the following records (the `T_Assessement` table in the code below) :

```
ID    RESULT_DT_TM           Author
1      2022-11-01 12:34.00   Brown 
4      2022-11-01 14:22.00   Molinari
```

The code I wrote is producing an error and I'm not quite sure how to fix it, I imagine its due to the `params`.

```
 for record in combined:
   start_date = combined['shift_start']
   end_date = combined['shift_end']
   author = combined['author']

T_Assessment = """
select * 
FROM NOTES
WHERE (DT_TM >= ? and DT_TM < ?) and (TITLE_TEXT = 'Assessment') and author = ?
"""
T_Assessment_v1 = pd.read_sql(T_Assessment,conn, params=[start_date,end_date,author])  


ERROR:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
select * 
FROM ED_NOTES_MASTER
WHERE (RESULT_DT_TM >= ? and RESULT_DT_TM < ?) and (RESULT_TITLE_TEXT = 'SZ ED Triage/Assessment') and author = ?
': ("A TVP's rows must be Sequence objects.", 'HY000')
```

Comment: The database/api is telling you what is wrong: 'The SQL contains 2 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied'. If you pass a statement with 2  question marks...then the number of parameters need to match. I suspect that the other error is a subtle typo. The variable: T_Assessement is never used (the pd.read_sql() call uses: T_Assessment (missing e)

Comment: Correct - I did have a typo but the error remains, albeit a different error. I corrected the typo and the error in the code above. T_Assessment is the name of the new table.

Comment: You confused `record` and `combined` in the first three lines of the loop body. Also, the indentation is off.